# How to set a local --repo-url to avoid fetch repo source code from googlesource?

Tags: repo

I use repo and gerrit to manage the source code. When I run repo init command

```
repo init -u gerrit_url/project -b branch_name
```

I see the repo try to fetch the source code from Google

```
Downloading Repo source from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo
```

I want to avoid it to access internet. So I git clone https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo then git push to gerrit_url/repo. Then I tried to use git clone gerrit_url/repo. It works. So I change my repo init command

```
repo init -u gerrit_url/project -b branch_name --repo-url gerrit_url/repo
```

But I got strange fail.

```
repo: error: "git" failed with exit status 128
cwd: /data/aken.hsu/Work/TEST/.repo/repo
cmd: ['git', 'describe', 'e7082ccb54ad870b185e99d7e39d1959c65ff899']
stderr:
>> fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

Anyone can help on this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

May be: copy gerrit_url/repo to your local disk (ex: /home/abc/gerrit_url/repo)
and use it while repo init:

```
repo init -u gerrit_url/project -b branch_name --repo-url=/home/abc/gerrit_url/repo
```

I think this is for using the same repo version as the version in the remote gerrit placed in the .repo/repo directory.
Otherwise, there may be a situation with errors, for example, in different versions of python (ex your code use python2 but in repo used python3).

Answer (score 0):

I reply my question. In fact, what I did is correct. But when I repo sync the Repo source code from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo, I added a option '--no-tags'.
But the repo init will find the tag of the Repo repository. So this error occurred.